RestFB page post with param scheduled_publish_time
public static void uploadVideo(String token, String urlVideo) {
    FacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(token, Version.LATEST);
    long scheduledTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + 30 * 60;
    FacebookType scheduledPostResponse = fbClient.publish("me/videos", FacebookType.class,
            Parameter.with("file_url", urlVideo),
            Parameter.with("published", false),
            Parameter.with("scheduled_publish_time", scheduledTime));

I want to post on the site with the condition that I schedule a posting appointment. I used restFB to successfully send the request and receive the ID back, but until now the post does not appear on the page
I have set up application development mode

When I go to business.facebook.com, it says can't post
